# generate multiple record according to the number of elements of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to write code that repeats as many times as array and then store data  to the database. I think this is to go well but didn't.
Is there something wrong?

Thanks.

```
def create
  product = Product.new
  product_params['type'].each do |t|
    product.name = product_params['name']
    product.about = product_params['about']
    product.type = t
    product.save    
  end
end

params.require(:product).permit(:name,:about, type: [])
```

Comment: FYI when asking why something doesn't work, you should also provide information on how it doesn't work. Like in this case - only one/the last product is created.

Comment: product.errors will show the error if it had failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Product instance needs to be initialized in the each iteration so that each time you will create a new record in the database instead of updating existing one:

```
def create
  product_params['type'].each do |t|
    Product.create(
      name: product_params['name'],
      about: product_params['about'],
      type: t
    )   
  end
end
```

Comment: @johnny you welcome. If my answer did help you please mark it as accepted by clicking on the green check mark near it

Comment: I checked it. I'm a beginner and I did not understand . Thank you for your helping!

Answer (score 2):

You're saving the same object multiple times. Try moving the `product = Product.new` line inside the `each` loop.